# how to call a function with parameter in jquery, if function is in parent div

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, root

I want to call a function with some parameters, But the function is in 3 or 4 parent div. How can i call that.

```
$("#bottom_bar #backbtn").click(function(){
        var $bottomLineBtn = $(this);
        $bottomLineBtn.parent().parent().parent().load_form('1', '55', 'update');

})
```

. ... in that target location ... like root div ... parent.parent.parent.div (btw i know how many parents are there)... the following function is written.

```
function load_form(list_index, record_id, form_action){
list_index = Number(list_index);
alert(list_index +" | "+ record_id +" | "+form_action);
}
```

Please help me... Thank you  please help

Comment: Usually you have onSomeEvent="Handler" for controls/DOM. You can trigger that event with .trigger("event"), there are some shortcuts as well (.click()).

Comment: what do you mean "the function is in 3 or 4 parent div"? Could you post that html fragment?

Comment: @morgar i've simplified my question.. please see this one..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887126/how-to-make-a-global-function-in-jquery-and-call-it-from-another-loaded-page

Comment: Still not sure why are you calling the function in the jquery chain and not simply with the function name, that is `load_form('1', '55', 'update');` only.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, i guess this is what you need:

```
$("#bottom_bar #backbtn").click(function(){
        var $bottomLineBtn = $(this);
        //Pass the div as an argument
        load_form('1', '55', 'update', $bottomLineBtn.parent().parent().parent());

})

function load_form(list_index, record_id, form_action, div){
  //Here you have a reference to the div in the 'div' var, if you need it
  list_index = Number(list_index);
  alert(list_index +" | "+ record_id +" | "+form_action);
}
```

Hope this helps.