# how to make a global function in jquery, and call it from another loaded page

Tags: jquery, function, parent-child, global

how to declare a global function in jquery, how do i call it from a page that was loaded in some div on that page using jquery's load() function.

the function is simple in **1st sub page**

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| main links                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------|
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
| |1st sub page (myfun function is here)      | |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
| | +---------------------------------------+ | |
| | |                                       | | |
| | |                                       | | |
| | |                                       | | |
| | | mybutton clicked myfun called         | | |
| | |                                       | | |
| | +---------------------------------------+ | |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

But when i click, nothing happens... 
here are both function

**myfun**

```
myfun(tab_index, acc_id){
    alert(tab_index +" | +" acc_id);
}
```

**mybutton**

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    var $bottomLineBtn = $(this);
    $bottomLineBtn.parent().myfun('2','43234');
})
```

Can somebody please help me.. its too hard to find the solution.. i've been searching for 3 hours...

**==================================================================================**

**updated**

here is the detailed scenario

1. i'm working on some dynamic stuff using jquery
2. the first page contains 2 divs, ones `id=menu` and others `id=subpage1`,
3. i click on one link from #menu, a page is loaded into `#subpage1`.
4. there is again a page with 2 divs  `#menu2` and `#subpage2`
5. here i made a script that loads pages automatically to `#subpage2` by taking only 1 parameter ....which is id of a listmenu.
6. this script is..

   ```
    $("#menu2 li").click(function(){
        $("#subpage2").load($(this).attr('page_link'));
      }
    }).filter('#menu2 li:eq(0)').click();
   ```
7. in the loaded page. at extreme bottom, i use 2 buttons, one button works fine, it calls the above function and change the value li:eq(1) .. that i did like this.

```
    $("#bottom_bar #backbtn").click(function(){
    var $bottomLineBtn = $(this);
    $bottomLineBtn.parent().parent().parent().find('#menu2 li:eq(1)').click();
    })
```

... but the other button doesn't work. i want to call a function that belongs with some divs in `#subpage1`. but can't access them. i put only a function, next to the above `$("#menu2 li").click(function(){` function.

```
 myfun(tab_index, acc_id){
        alert(tab_index +" | +" acc_id);
    }
```

but i don't know how to call this function from the 2nd button loaded into `#subpage2`

does the above scenario make scene.. please try to understand me.. i'm not very good in description...

Comment: Sub pages? Do you mean IFRAMEs or what?

Comment: If you're loading the content with `load()` then it is important where your `$('#mybutton').click(...)` is defined.  Your button may not exist when the event is bound.

Comment: @Orbling sub pages mean.. pages loaded using jquery into some div

Comment: That would be called dynamic content, sub page is not a standard expression in HTML/AJAX/JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why can't you put your function in an external .js file and then import it into your main page?

Comment: @slandau ...good idea .. but i don't know.. that is also not working

Comment: @MFarooqi: Generally, JS is best in separate files, not on the page with the HTML.

Comment: @Obling that is fine.. i also try to keep my functions in any js file.. but while using in jquery.. some of my functions doesn't work... .. i think because of.. "$(document).ready.... i've called this on every page, on every event.. is this wrong?...

Comment: Your functions should always work. The only thing .ready() and .live() should be doing is letting your functions know WHEN they should be called.

Comment: Thank you very much... every one.. that is resolved with just re-making of scripts.. in very few lines.. may be 4, or 5... :) thank you so much...

Answer (score 4):

```
function setGlobalFunc()
{    
   window.myfunc = (function(){alert("o hai");});    
}    

setGlobalFunc();    
myfunc();
```

Function created from within another function, still globaly accessible.

No jQuery required at all.

Answer (score 2):

If content is loaded dynamically, events need to be hooked up using the `.live()` method

```
$("#mybutton").live("click", function() { /* code here */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you chain the function as if it is part of jQuery, but you have not made it be a plugin to the jQuery.

you should call it like this

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    // var $bottomLineBtn = $(this);
    // $bottomLineBtn.parent();
    myfun('2','43234');
})
```

---

or define your function as a plugin of jquery like

```
 $.fn.myfun = function(tab_index, acc_id){
    alert(tab_index +" | +" acc_id);
 };
```

and call it as you currently do